# How do you move users/posts/settings from one vBulletin installation to another?

Tags: mysql, backup, forum, vbulletin

I have a vBulletin installation that was recently defaced as a result of a sql injection flaw in the VB search interface. I'd like to move all of the posts/threads/permissions/users from the old database to a new database in which I just freshly installed vBulletin. Their impex program won't help with this, as it seems to only be able to import data from old versions of vBulletin, not from one vBulletin 4.x database to another. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as ImpEx does not support it, you may install another forum software (phpbb, smf, ipb), import your data to this installation using their tools which likely support importing from vb4, and after that import content from this installation to your new vbulletin 4 installation using impex.

There are some disadvantages however:

1. You may have to re-set your permissions because of the differences in permission systems in different software.
2. Your user's passwords will become invalid and they will have to recover them via email. This, however, might be considered as a plus because your db was compromised, password hashes and salts could have leaked and knowing this it isn't very hard to bruteforce someone's password on modern hardware.